# How to remove "Paypal" from error text on credit card decline

Tags: paypal

When a customer attempts to place an order that gets declined they get an error along the lines of (paraphrasing): "Paypal Gateway decline: *some error code*". Is there any way to remove the "Paypal" part of that message? We have a number of business & government customers that are not allowed to use paypal and freak out when they see that message and cannot be made to understand that Paypal business is not the same as "Paypal" that they're thinking of.

Answer (score 4):

In your app/locale/en_US/Mage_Paypal.cvs (replace en_US with any store language you may use) simply find the lines and remove the word Paypal from the 'translation'.

eg:

```
"PayPal gateway has rejected request. %s","PayPal gateway has rejected request. %s"
```

becomes

```
"PayPal gateway has rejected request. %s","The Gateway has rejected request. %s"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check on this. It seems like exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the merchant country in admin settings for PayPal.
Then check the PayPal id used in Magento PayPal payment method is not used before in any other store. 
Check where the PayPal account is not limited due any reason.
This error is related to your PayPal email id and merchant country only.
Thats why PayPal gateway rejecting the redirect request.
Hope this will help you...!!